# How to manage threads with locks and custom condition with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

In a Spring application the goal is to have multiple threads running, 1 of each "type" at a time.
When running  together type1, type2, type3, type3, only the first 3 are running (concurrently), but the last one seems to stay blocked and doesn't run.

```
class MyClass{
    
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition shouldRun = lock.newCondition();
    private Set<String> currentRunningTypes = Sets.newHashSet();

    @Async
    public void process(String type){
        try{
            log.info("Starting type {}", type);
            lock.lock();
            while(currentRunningTypes.contains(type)) {
                log.info("waiting for type {}", type);
                shouldRun.await();
            }
            currentRunningTypes.add(type);
            lock.unlock();

            doSomething(type);

        } finally {
            log.info("Type ended {}", type);
            if(lock.isLocked) {
                lock.unlock;
            }
        }

    }

    private void doSomething(String type) {
        //... process
        currentRunningTypes.remove(type)
        shouldRun.signalAll();
    }

}
```

The output:

```
Starting type type1
Starting type type2
Starting type type3
Starting type type4
waiting for type type4
Type ended type1
Type ended type2
Type ended type3
```

The expected output:

```
Starting type type1
Starting type type2
Starting type type3
Starting type type4
waiting for type type4
Type ended type1
Type ended type2
Type ended type3
Type ended type4
```

Why isn't the thread starting?